# Implementation of Rank and Dense Rank in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

Hi I am a Begineer in MySql and I want to Implement Rank and Dense Rank Function on MySql for the given problem statement stated below. 
 I have a Table called `Transaction` which has following Columns:

```
Transaction_no | Register|Adult|child
```

The Input Data is as follows:
INPUT

```
+----------------+----------+-------+-------+
| transaction_no | register | adult | child |
+----------------+----------+-------+-------+
|           1234 |        A |     0 |     1 |
|           1234 |        A |     1 |     2 |
|           1234 |        A |     1 |     1 |
|           3456 |        B |     1 |     0 |
|           5678 |        B |     1 |     0 |
|           2468 |        C |     1 |     0 |
|           2468 |        C |     0 |     1 |
+----------------+----------+-------+-------+
```

My Requirement is to add another column namely **rn** using mySQL which will use Rank and dense rank like logic to generate the following intermediate output

INTERMEDIATE

```
+----------------+----------+-------+-------+----+
| transaction_no | register | adult | child | rn | 
+----------------+----------+-------+-------+----+
|           1234 |        A |     0 |     1 |  1 |
|           1234 |        A |     1 |     2 |  2 |
|           1234 |        A |     1 |     1 |  3 |
|           3456 |        B |     1 |     0 |  1 |
|           5678 |        B |     1 |     0 |  1 |
|           2468 |        C |     1 |     0 |  1 |
|           2468 |        C |     0 |     1 |  2 |
+----------------+----------+-------+-------+----+
```

Here the partition is done on transaction number.

The Final Query Output should contain all the rows whose **rn**=1 and the rn value should not displayed.
OUTPUT

```
+----------------+----------+-------+-------+
| transaction_no | register | adult | child |
+----------------+----------+-------+-------+
|           1234 |        A |     0 |     1 |
|           3456 |        B |     1 |     0 |
|           5678 |        B |     1 |     0 |
|           2468 |        C |     1 |     0 |
+----------------+----------+-------+-------+
```

Oracle Documentation for Reference : [OracleDocument](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm)

I have also added SQL fiddle for Reference.[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79c00/17)

Please help me on this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use *only* the relevant tags - since your question apparently is about MySQL, I'd suggest you remove the SQL-Server and Oracle tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MySQL Solution**:

```
SELECT transaction_no, register, adult, child
  FROM (
         SELECT
                ( CASE WHEN @prev_tno != transaction_no THEN @rn:=1 
                       ELSE @rn:=(@rn+1) END ) AS rn
              , @prev_tno:=transaction_no AS transaction_no
              , register, adult, child
           FROM instructor
              , (SELECT @rn:=0, @prev_tno:=NULL) AS row_nums
       ) src
 WHERE rn = 1
 ORDER BY register, transaction_no
```

**Note**: Desired ordering can only be achieved on explicit request, hence `ORDER BY` is used in the query.

Comment: **@shubhamagiwal**: which part of the query?

Comment: The inner Select of the whole query.

Comment: Inner query uses a session variable to buffer a value from current row and compares on the next row. if matches then increments the rank number else resets it.

Comment: Hi Ravinder Can you please Explain me the importance of this part of the query (SELECT rn:=0, prev_tno:=NULL) I am unable to understand what is its requirement.

Comment: It is to initialize session variables to use in the query. Unless which you may need a stored procedure to remember the value read in the current row and compare the same during next row values reading.

Comment: Read [`User-Defined Variables`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (TransactionId int,register VARCHAR(1),Adult INT,Child INT )
insert into @t (TransactionId,register,Adult,Child)values (1234,'A',0,1),
(1234,'A',1,2),(1234,'A',1,1),(3456,'B',1,0),(5678,'B',1,0),(2468,'C',1,0),(2468,'C',0,1)
;with cte as (
select TransactionId,register,Adult,Child,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY TransactionId,register  ORDER BY register ) RN from @t
)
Select TransactionId,register,Adult,Child from cte where RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

create table TRANSACTION
    (
    Transaction_no int,
    Register varchar2(2),
    Adult int,
    child int
    );

Insert rows in TRANSACTION table.

Sqlquery for Intermediate output:-

select TRANSACTION_NO,REGISTER,Adult,child, DENSE_RANK() over(PARTITION BY REGISTER ORDER BY Adult,child) as rnk  from TRANSACTION;

Sqlquery for Final output:-

select TRANSACTION_NO,REGISTER,Adult,child from (
select TRANSACTION_NO,REGISTER,Adult,child, DENSE_RANK() over(PARTITION BY TRANSACTION_NO ORDER BY Adult,child) as rnk  from TRANSACTION)
where rnk=1;

I tried it on Oracle.